# Different files on shared partition?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning

I am dual-booting Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04. My partition scheme looks like this:

```
/dev/sda1 - Windows 8 (nfts)
/dev/sda2 - Ubuntu / (ext4)
/dev/sda3 - Ubuntu home (ext4)
/dev/sda5 - swap
/dev/sda6 - Shared data partition (exfat)
```

(First off, yes I do have exfat libraries installed on Ubuntu)

I created some PNG images in Windows and saved them on my shared partition. From Ubuntu, I edited the images in GIMP and saved them (replacing the ones on the shared partition).

When I boot into Windows, the files appear unchanged - exactly like they did before I edited them from Ubuntu. I even added a folder and deleted some other files, but none of these changes exist in Windows.

When I boot into Ubuntu, all of the changes are still there.

It is as if Windows is caching the old file structure...

How is this possible? Thanks in advance.

**Edit -- commands output**

~~ lsblk

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 165.1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0  21.3G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0  98.9G  0 part /home
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 172.7G  0 part /mnt/shared_data
```

~~ /etc/fstab

```
# <file system>                 <mount point>       <type>  <options>           <dump>  <pass>
proc                        /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

# /dev/sda2
UUID=8f700f65-b5c7-4afc-a6fb-8f9271e0fb5e   /           ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1

# /dev/sda3
UUID=f0d688b7-22bd-4fa7-bc1b-a594af2933fa       /home               ext4    defaults        0       2

# /dev/sda5
UUID=3bc2399b-5deb-4f04-924b-d4fc77491997   none            swap    sw          0       0

# /dev/sda6
UUID=F2DE-BC47                  /mnt/shared_data    exfat   defaults        0   3
```

~~ /etc/mtab

```
/dev/sda2 / ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sda3 /home ext4 rw 0 0

/dev/sda6 /mnt/shared_data fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0

binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/matt/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=matt 0 0
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of the commands "lsblk", "cat /etc/fstab" and "cat /etc/mtab"!

Comment: In /etc/fstab I changed the mount options from 'defaults' to 'rw' and that fixed it. I don't know very much about the fstab file though, is this a permanent fix or was it just coincidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and mark this as solved. Changing the mount options from **defaults** to **rw** worked.

From the Linux help files:

> **sync and async**
>
> How the input and output to the filesystem should be done. sync means
> it's done synchronously. If you look at the example fstab, you'll
> notice that this is the option used with the floppy. In plain English,
> this means that when you, for example, copy a file to the floppy, the
> changes are physically written to the floppy at the same time you
> issue the copy command.
>
> However, if you have the async option in
> /etc/fstab, input and output is done asynchronously. Now when you copy
> a file to the floppy, the changes may be physically written to it long
> time after issuing the command. This isn't bad, and may sometimes be
> favorable, but can cause some nasty accidents: if you just remove the
> floppy without unmounting it first, the copied file may not physically
> exist on the floppy yet!
>
> async is the default. However, it may be wise
> to use sync with the floppy, especially if you're used to the way it's
> done in Windows and have a tendency to remove floppies before
> unmounting them first.

The **defaults** mount option includes the **async** option. I assume this is what was causing the problem, but I'm still not sure. If anyone knows why, please comment.